# How to concatenate string in a for loop using scanner?

Tags: java

package exercises;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SentenceBuilder {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MAX_WORDS = 5;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word ="";

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter word "+(i+1)+" of "+MAX_WORDS);
        word = scan.nextLine();

    }
    System.out.println(word);// im stuck on how to concatenate the result

}
```

}

Comment: Have a look at the `StringBuilder` class.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `for`:

```
word = word + scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: thanks for the help